# Create a DateTime for tomorrow Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datetime

I know I can create `Date.tomorrow` and there are options like `midnight`, `at_noon` etc.  I need a more specific time than this.

Specifically, I am looking to create a DateTime that is tomorrow at 11am.  I don't see anything in the DateTime docs.  Is there any simple way to accomplish this?  Thanks!

Comment: `Date.tomorrow` is not available in Ruby. You might want to tag your post with [tag:activesupport] and/or [tag:rails] if applicable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Rails you would probably use [`tomorrow`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#method-c-tomorrow), [`in_time_zone`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Zones.html#method-i-in_time_zone) and [`change`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-change):

```
Date.tomorrow.in_time_zone.change(hour: 11)
#=> Sat, 08 Aug 2015 11:00:00 CEST +02:00
```

This returns a `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` instance, just like `midnight`, `at_noon` etc.

Answer (score 3):

Pure Ruby:

```
(Date.today + 1).to_datetime + Rational(11, 24)
```

or equivalently,

```
Date.today.to_datetime + Rational(35, 24)
```

Comment: Can `35.0/24` be substituted for `Rational(35,24)`? I see `Date.today.to_datetime + Rational(35,24) == Date.today.to_datetime + 35.0/24` returns `true`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Seems it can. I prefer `Rational` because it is more exact, but it seems the precision is sufficient for this purpose.